# UIImagePickerController and UIButton background images

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, uiimagepickercontroller

I can successfully take a photo and set it to the background image for a button. The problem is that the image gets smushed. Should I be setting a crop on it or what am I missing for this to render the image correctly. Thanks.

Comment: check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode

Comment: Will do. I'll comment later on my successes. Thanks again Mateusz

Comment: I set the scale to view in the IB for the button, but after going through all the options available, the image is still renders incorrectly as the image for the button. The button has a width and height of 250 111 respectively.

Comment: can you give some screenshots (how it looks now and how it supposed to) and some code? Because I'm not sure if I understand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After properly using constraints in the IB, the image then set to the button in a normal format. I found out that having dotted lines on the view controller due to constraints is a bad thing. After doing constraints the right way, the image showed perfectly. Thanks all for the help.